# Finding the first Preceding Sibling with a particular element

Tags: xslt

Given The following XML:

```
<Root>
  <NodeA>
    <ChildNodeA/>
    <ChildNodeB/>
  </NodeA>
  <NodeB>
    <ChildNodeB/>
  </NodeB>
  <NodeC>
  </NodeC>
</Root>
```

How do I find the first Preceding Siblilng of a particular Node that contains a particular Element.

I.E. If I am at "NodeC" how do I find the first Sibling with "ChildNodeA", in this instance "NodeA"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the first preceding sibling that contains a child element is quite straight-forward, and indeed closely matches the way you describe it....

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::*[ChildNodeA][1]" />
```

Assuming your were positioned on **NodeC**, this would indeed return your **NodeA** in your case

```
<NodeA>
  <ChildNodeA></ChildNodeA>
  <ChildNodeB></ChildNodeB>
</NodeA>
```